# Не могу избавиться от символов в json python

Tags: python

Не могу избавиться от символов в json python.

Использую **ensure_ascii=False** получаю следующий json:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без **ensure_ascii=False**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import json
        
dictionary = {
     'name': 'Курс MIT «Безопасность компьютерных систем». Лекция 11: «Язык программирования Ur/Web», часть 1'
}
        
with open("data_file2.json", "w") as write_file:
     json.dump(dictionary, write_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: open("data_file2.json", "w", encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Сергей Ш, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, проблема в кодировке выходного файла, попробуй добавить UTF8 при открытии этого файла

```
with open("data_file2.json", "w", encoding='UTF8') as write_file:
     json.dump(dictionary, write_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```